# How to compile opencv application using opencv static libs?

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I compile OpenCV4 by statically link:

> cmake
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/opencv4-static -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DOPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON ../

add the `pkgconfig` in the path:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/pkgconfig
```

then compile a sample:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.9 -std=c++11 videocapture_basic.cpp -o camera `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs --static`
```

but got a lot of errors:

```
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::ExrDecoder::readHeader()' :
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x6): `Imf::globalThreadCount()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x18): `Imf::InputFile::InputFile(char const*, int)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x20): `Imf::InputFile::header() const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x26): `Imf::Header::dataWindow() const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x4e): `Imf::InputFile::header() const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x52): `Imf::hasChromaticities(Imf::Header const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x5a): `Imf::InputFile::header() const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x5e): `Imf::Header::channels() const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x68): `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x74): `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x80): `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xa8): `Imf::InputFile::header() const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xac): `Imf::chromaticities(Imf::Header const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xf8): `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x10c): `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x118): `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::ExrDecoder::newDecoder() const' :
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cv10ExrDecoder10newDecoderEv+0xba): `Imf::Chromaticities::Chromaticities(Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&)' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::ExrDecoder::ExrDecoder()' :
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoderC2Ev+0x84): `Imf::Chromaticities::Chromaticities(Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&)' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::ExrDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)' :
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x140): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x14c): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x19c): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1a8): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1f2): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1fe): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x24e): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x25a): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x2aa): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x2b6): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x300): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x30c): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x31a): `Imf::FrameBuffer::begin()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x35a): `Imf::FrameBuffer::end()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x366): `Imf::InputFile::setFrameBuffer(Imf::FrameBuffer const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x3a2): `Imf::InputFile::readPixels(int, int)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x6e0): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x6ec): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x716): `Imf::InputFile::readPixels(int, int)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xd46): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xd52): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xd8c): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xd98): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xdd0): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xddc): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xe40): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xe4c): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xe86): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xe92): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xee0): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xeec): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::ExrEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)' :
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x54): `Imf::Header::Header(int, int, float, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, float, Imf::LineOrder, Imf::Compression)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xe0): `Imf::Header::channels()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xf2): `Imf::Channel::Channel(Imf::PixelType, int, int, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xfe): `Imf::ChannelList::insert(char const*, Imf::Channel const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x108): `Imf::globalThreadCount()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x118): `Imf::OutputFile::OutputFile(char const*, Imf::Header const&, int)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x198): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1a8): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1b0): `Imf::OutputFile::setFrameBuffer(Imf::FrameBuffer const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1b8): `Imf::OutputFile::writePixels(int)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x218): `Imf::OutputFile::~OutputFile()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x21e): `Imf::Header::~Header()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x252): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x262): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x288): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x294): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2b8): `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2c4): `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2ca): `Imf::Header::channels()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2dc): `Imf::Channel::Channel(Imf::PixelType, int, int, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2e8): `Imf::ChannelList::insert(char const*, Imf::Channel const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2ee): `Imf::Header::channels()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x300): `Imf::Channel::Channel(Imf::PixelType, int, int, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x30c): `Imf::ChannelList::insert(char const*, Imf::Channel const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x312): `Imf::Header::channels()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x324): `Imf::Channel::Channel(Imf::PixelType, int, int, bool)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x330): `Imf::ChannelList::insert(char const*, Imf::Channel const&)' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x366): `Imf::Header::~Header()' 
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x456): `Imf::OutputFile::~OutputFile()' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::JasperInitializer::~JasperInitializer()' :
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv17JasperInitializerD2Ev[_ZN2cv17JasperInitializerD5Ev]+0x4): `jas_cleanup' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder_close(cv::Jpeg2KDecoder*)' :
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL19Jpeg2KDecoder_closeEPNS_13Jpeg2KDecoderE+0x8): `jas_stream_close' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL19Jpeg2KDecoder_closeEPNS_13Jpeg2KDecoderE+0x14): `jas_image_destroy' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader()' :
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x14): `jas_stream_close' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x22): `jas_image_destroy' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x32): `jas_stream_fopen' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x46): `jas_image_decode' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x13e): `jas_stream_close' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x14c): `jas_image_destroy' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::close()' :
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder5closeEv+0x8): `jas_stream_close' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder5closeEv+0x14): `jas_image_destroy' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)' :
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xc4): `jas_image_getcmptbytype' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xd0): `jas_image_getcmptbytype' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xdc): `jas_image_getcmptbytype' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x146): `jas_matrix_create' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x160): `jas_image_readcmpt' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x19a): `jas_matrix_destroy' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x2de): `jas_image_getcmptbytype' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x2f0): `jas_cmprof_createfromclrspc' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x302): `jas_image_chclrspc' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x30e): `jas_image_destroy' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x31a): `jas_cmprof_destroy' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x396): `jas_matrix_destroy' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x408): `jas_cmprof_destroy' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent8u(void*, cv::Mat const&)' :
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x1e): `jas_matrix_create' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x8a): `jas_image_writecmpt' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0xa2): `jas_matrix_destroy' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent16u(void*, cv::Mat const&)' :
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x20): `jas_matrix_create' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x8c): `jas_image_writecmpt' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0xa0): `jas_matrix_destroy' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)' :
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x6c): `jas_image_create' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xa4): `jas_image_destroy' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xb8): `jas_image_create' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xec): `jas_stream_fopen' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xfa): `jas_image_strtofmt' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x108): `jas_image_encode' 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x114): `jas_stream_close' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): undefined reference to `_GLOBAL__sub_I_grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp' :
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp+0x2): `jas_init' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::my_jpeg_load_dht(jpeg_decompress_struct*, unsigned char*, JHUFF_TBL**, JHUFF_TBL**) [clone .constprop.59]' :
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text.unlikely._ZN2cvL16my_jpeg_load_dhtEP22jpeg_decompress_structPhPP9JHUFF_TBLS5_.constprop.59+0xaa): `jpeg_alloc_huff_table' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::JpegEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)' :
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x76): `jpeg_CreateCompress' 
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a(color_rgb.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::hal::cvtGraytoBGR(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, unsigned int, int, int, int, int)' :
color_rgb.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal12cvtGraytoBGREPKhjPhjiiii+0x82): `carotene_o4t::isSupportedConfiguration()' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a(color_yuv.cpp.o): undefined reference to `TegraCvtColor_rgb2ycrcb_Invoker::operator()(cv::Range const&) const' :
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZNK31TegraCvtColor_rgb2ycrcb_InvokerclERKN2cv5RangeE[_ZNK31TegraCvtColor_rgb2ycrcb_InvokerclERKN2cv5RangeE]+0x2a): `carotene_o4t::rgb2ycrcb(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a(color_yuv.cpp.o): undefined reference to `TegraCvtColor_bgr2ycrcb_Invoker::operator()(cv::Range const&) const' :
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZNK31TegraCvtColor_bgr2ycrcb_InvokerclERKN2cv5RangeE[_ZNK31TegraCvtColor_bgr2ycrcb_InvokerclERKN2cv5RangeE]+0x2a): `carotene_o4t::bgr2ycrcb(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a(color_yuv.cpp.o): undefined reference to `TegraCvtColor_rgbx2ycrcb_Invoker::operator()(cv::Range const&) const' :
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZNK32TegraCvtColor_rgbx2ycrcb_InvokerclERKN2cv5RangeE[_ZNK32TegraCvtColor_rgbx2ycrcb_InvokerclERKN2cv5RangeE]+0x2a): `carotene_o4t::rgbx2ycrcb(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a(color_yuv.cpp.o): undefined reference to `TegraCvtColor_bgrx2ycrcb_Invoker::operator()(cv::Range const&) const' :
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZNK32TegraCvtColor_bgrx2ycrcb_InvokerclERKN2cv5RangeE[_ZNK32TegraCvtColor_bgrx2ycrcb_InvokerclERKN2cv5RangeE]+0x2a): `carotene_o4t::bgrx2ycrcb(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a(color_yuv.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::hal::cvtBGRtoYUV(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, unsigned int, int, int, int, int, bool, bool)' :
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal11cvtBGRtoYUVEPKhjPhjiiiibb+0xd2): `carotene_o4t::isSupportedConfiguration()' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a(color_yuv.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::hal::cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGR(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, unsigned int, int, int, int, bool, int)' :
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal19cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGREPKhjPhjiiibi+0x22): `carotene_o4t::isSupportedConfiguration()' 
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal19cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGREPKhjPhjiiibi+0x88): `carotene_o4t::yuv420i2bgr(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal19cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGREPKhjPhjiiibi+0xc2): `carotene_o4t::yuv420i2rgbx(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal19cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGREPKhjPhjiiibi+0xec): `carotene_o4t::yuv420sp2rgb(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal19cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGREPKhjPhjiiibi+0x116): `carotene_o4t::yuv420sp2rgbx(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal19cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGREPKhjPhjiiibi+0x128): `carotene_o4t::yuv420i2rgb(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal19cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGREPKhjPhjiiibi+0x13a): `carotene_o4t::yuv420i2bgrx(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal19cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGREPKhjPhjiiibi+0x14c): `carotene_o4t::yuv420sp2bgr(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
color_yuv.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal19cvtTwoPlaneYUVtoBGREPKhjPhjiiibi+0x152): `carotene_o4t::yuv420sp2bgrx(carotene_o4t::Size2D const&, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char*, int)' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::Impl::rewind()' :
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl6rewindEv[_ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl6rewindEv]+0x1a): `gzrewind' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::Impl::closeFile()' :
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl9closeFileEv[_ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl9closeFileEv]+0x24): `gzclose' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::Impl::eof()' :
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl3eofEv[_ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl3eofEv]+0x38): `gzeof' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::Impl::puts(char const*)' :
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4putsEPKc[_ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4putsEPKc]+0x6a): `gzputs' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::Impl::gets(char*, int)' :
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4getsEPci[_ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4getsEPci]+0x128): `gzgets' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::Impl::gets()' :
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4getsEv[_ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4getsEv]+0x104): `gzeof' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::Impl::release(std::string*) [clone .constprop.294]' :
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl7releaseEPSs.constprop.294+0x1e4): `gzclose' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::releaseAndGetString()' :
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage19releaseAndGetStringEv+0x25c): `gzclose' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::Impl::open(char const*, int, char const*)' :
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4openEPKciS3_[_ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4openEPKciS3_]+0x69e): `gzopen' 
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4openEPKciS3_[_ZN2cv11FileStorage4Impl4openEPKciS3_]+0x7d0): `gzrewind' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

it looks like didn't link the 3rd libs.

I want a version of OpenCV libs with dependencies(libstd..) or complete static OpenCV libs.

## Found something:

Looks like it's a BUG of `pkg-config`,
`pkg-config --static` not worked. so the 3rd libs didn't link.

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.9 -std=c++11 videocapture_basic.cpp -o camera `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs` -L/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/opencv4/3rdparty -lquirc -llibprotobuf -ltegra_hal -lzlib -llibjpeg-turbo -llibwebp -llibpng -llibtiff -llibjasper -lIlmImf -L/home/atmark/opencv-4.0.1/static-build/lib -lade -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt
```

Now error remains only:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.9 -std=c++11 videocapture_basic.cpp -o camera `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs` -L/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/opencv4/3rdparty -lquirc -llibprotobuf -ltegra_hal -lzlib -llibjpeg-turbo -llibwebp -llibpng -llibtiff -llibjasper -lIlmImf -L/home/atmark/opencv-4.0.1/static-build/lib -lade -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/opencv4/3rdparty/libIlmImf.a(ImfZipCompressor.cpp.o): undefined reference to `Imf::ZipCompressor::compress(char const*, int, int, char const*&)' :
ImfZipCompressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf13ZipCompressor8compressEPKciiRS2_+0xa0): `compress' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/opencv4/3rdparty/libIlmImf.a(ImfZipCompressor.cpp.o): undefined reference to `Imf::ZipCompressor::uncompress(char const*, int, int, char const*&)' :
ImfZipCompressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf13ZipCompressor10uncompressEPKciiRS2_+0x28): `uncompress' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/opencv4/3rdparty/libIlmImf.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp.o): undefined reference to `Imf::Pxr24Compressor::compress(char const*, int, Imath::Box<Imath::Vec2<int> >, char const*&) [clone .part.3]' :
ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf15Pxr24Compressor8compressEPKciN5Imath3BoxINS3_4Vec2IiEEEERS2_.part.3+0x17e): `compress' 
/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/opencv4/3rdparty/libIlmImf.a(ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp.o): undefined reference to `Imf::Pxr24Compressor::uncompress(char const*, int, Imath::Box<Imath::Vec2<int> >, char const*&) [clone .part.4]' :
ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:(.text._ZN3Imf15Pxr24Compressor10uncompressEPKciN5Imath3BoxINS3_4Vec2IiEEEERS2_.part.4+0x28): `uncompress' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why the "c" tag? Also, if a piece of software doesn't work as expected (including compiling it), you should write a bug report. If you want to discuss the problem itself here, you'd have to extract a [mcve] first.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt SO recommended "c" tag

Comment: It was just a recommendation which you don't have to follow. Be smart, make an informed decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by disabling OpenEXR `-DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF` of OpenCV:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/opencv4-static -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DOPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF ../
```

And compile the application with static std libs:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.9 -std=c++11 videocapture_basic.cpp -o camera `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs` -L/home/atmark/opencv4-static/lib/opencv4/3rdparty -lquirc -llibprotobuf -ltegra_hal -lzlib -llibjpeg-turbo -llibwebp -llibpng -llibtiff -llibjasper -L/home/atmark/opencv-4.0.1/static-build/lib -lade -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```